# SQL Performance/Advantages of selectin data from table and same data from View on same table

Tags: sql-server

Why it is suggested to select the data from View on particular table rather than selecting directly from table.

eg. I have

```
select * from table1 --Not recommended

create view test (

select * from table1

) 


select * from view - Recommended.
```

Is it beccause of locking issue or else (using mssql 2008 R2)

Comment: A good start is [Scenarios For Using Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188250(v=sql.105).aspx).  To expand on Vikdor's answer, you can also restrict access to rows, e.g. only show sales data more than 6 months old.

Answer (score 1):

Views are generally recommended to

- hide the underlying table structure i.e. have calculated columns or transformed ones etc.,
- manage access at a granular level i.e. grant access to only certain columns in a table

Comment: Thanks Vikdor, you have suggsted correctly from Security perspective. Can you suggest something in respect to locking and performance.

Comment: @NishadMankar, The data returned by views is not physically separate from that of the underlying table(s). A view is executed when referred to. So, views do not improve locking or performance as such.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen this recommendation - a source would be good!

As Vikdor says, there are reasons to use a view - security, and abstracting away logic around the underlying data; they have no impact on performance.

In fact, your example would be considered an anti-pattern, because views don't automatically recognize changes to the underlying table; every time you change your "table1", you'd have to re-create the view.

I've also seen some cases where the query optimizer got a little confused by accessing views, and the resulting queries were slower than querying the base tables. This is highly platform and version specific, but with complex queries, it can be an issue.

Materialized views may have performance benefits, especially when the view stores complex calculations.